How to get authInfo in the callback's request?
I'm using passport and google oauth strategy using session, and the authentication works fine, the issue is that based on the authInfo, I need to redirect to a different URL. If it's a new user, redirect to page A, if it's an existing user, redirect to page B.
The issue with nest is that request.authInfo is always undefined inside the callback function, like this:
@UseGuards(GoogleAuthGuard)
@Get('/google/callback')
async googleCallback(
  @Request()
  request: ExpressRequest,
): Promise<void> {
  console.log(request.authInfo); // This is undefined
}

But, in my auth guard, the request.authInfo is defined and I can see the value stored there, like this:
handleRequest<TUser = UserOutput>(
  err: Error | null,
  user: TUser,
  info: { newUser: boolean },
  context: ExecutionContext,
): TUser {
  const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

  console.log(request.authInfo); // This works

  return user;
}

The thing is that I need the authInfo in my callback function so I can redirect the user to the right page, but for some reason it's always undefined there. Maybe this is a bug in @nestjs/passport package, but I'm not sure
